# Create an app where I can physically write things out with my finger

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an app where I can physically write things out with my finger and erase them? Something like a big sticky note that you can just write on?

How Would do this, i am really new to programming so i would really appreciate your help.

My question is similar to a question asked here, so i just edited it his question

http://androidforums.com/android-applications/104361-notepad-app-widget-actually-lets-you-write-notes.html

any code, books, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [SO], please try to research your topic thoroughly before posting questions as per the [FAQ].  Also if somebody has posted an answer that resolves your issue you should accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `TouchPaint` sample in your samples/ApiDemos directory. In this app you can draw lines on the screen with your fingers.

Here is the [online link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html).